# Include class from lib folder in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I have a class in my `lib` folder with two methods to be used in the app, spec, and a rake command.

The class looks like:

```
class LibClass

  def method_1
    ...
  end

  def method_2(item)
    ...
  end
end
```

In my model, I have:

```
require "lib_clas"

class Model < ApplicationRecord

  def model_method
    LibClass.method_1
  end

end
```

The error I get is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `method_1' for LibClass:Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are trying to call instance method by class. You should instantiate an object for the class first if you want to access instance methods.

Can you make the following changes?

`LibClass.method_1` to `LibClass.new.method_1`

You can read more about it here: https://medium.com/@weberzt/class-vs-instance-methods-in-ruby-da4de44ac6a0

Comment: Alternatively, define the method on the class `class LibClass ; def self.method1 ; ... `

Comment: Yeah that should also solve the issue shown above and also looks more cleaner when accessing the method. Totally depends on the use case for using one of the solutions now.

Comment: I ended up using `self.method1` and that works locally. But when I try to use in docker containers it doesn't throws an error `uninitialized constant LibClass`